# error asp:Literal change position tag html after assign value?

Tags: asp.net

```
    <asp:Literal ID="literal" runat="server"  >
         </asp:Literal>
```

i using string have value below

```
<div class="TopNewsTab">
    <div class="news-category">
        <div class="c1">
            <div class="c11">

            </div>
            <div class="c12" />
            <div class="c13" />
        </div>
        <div class="news-content">
        </div>
     </div>

    <div class="news-category">
        <div class="c1">
            <div class="c11">

            </div>
            <div class="c12" />
            <div class="c13" />
        </div>
        <div class="news-content">
        </div>
     </div>

</div>
```

after i  using literal.Text= valueover;

when display on page i used firebug  see content  become

```
<div class="TopNewsTab">
    <div class="news-category">
        <div class="c1">
            <div class="c11">

            </div>
            <div class="c12" />

             **<div class="news-category">
                 <div class="c1">
                   <div class="c11">

                  </div>
                  <div class="c12" />
                  <div class="c13" />

              </div>**

        <div class="news-content">
        </div>
     </div>
        <div class="c13" />
        </div>
        <div class="news-content">
        </div>
     </div>

</div>
```

position of `<div class="news-category">` change position before assign literal please help me the problem ??

Comment: Why are you adding so much markup to the literal (from I'm guessing code behind)?

Comment: I added  markup to literal in code  behind  but still have an problem same

Answer (score 1):

Don't self close your `<div/>` tags. I know it seems like it should technically be valid in XHTML, but it causes problems.

So just change

```
<div class="c12" />
<div class="c13" />
```

to

```
<div class="c12" ></div>
<div class="c13" ></div>
```

Comment: You should mark this is the answer by clicking the check mark, that is how we keep score on this website. Welcome to SO